# Archiving Emails: Multiple Transports in Postfix?

Tags: linux, email, postfix, archive

I'm trying to archive incoming mail by routing it to a PHP script (which inserts it into a database) before sending the email to the destination server.

If I configure my /etc/postfix/transport as such:

```
example.com smtp:[192.168.1.100]
```

My email will then be forwarded to the Exchange server (192.168.1.100 for testing) to the appropriate mailbox.

If I configure my /etc/postfix/transport as such:

```
example.com myarchive:
```

Then incoming email is piped to a PHP script and inserted into a database, however it never makes it to Exchange.

I've tried adding multiple transports

```
example.com myarchive:    smtp:[192.168.1.100]
```

But it only makes it to the first one listed (I've tried both ways). Can something like this be achieved to archive a mail before sending it on its merry way?

Note: "myarchive" is set up in `/etc/postifx/master.cf` as:

```
myarchiver   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=mailarchive argv=/home/mailarchive/pipe.php
  ${nexthop} ${user}
```

Answer (score 4):

Postfix cannot deliver a message to multiple destinations. You can however use the [`always_bcc`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#always_bcc) directive to automatically BCC all messages to another address. You still need to configure the transports to deliver messages to the special archive address to your script.

```
always_bcc = archive@archive.example.com
```

Comment: I had that working, but didn't like the BCC'ing part. Thanks though.